# Generate ServiceNow Tickets from application logs

Tags: servicenow

ServiceNow integration with application

I have a spring boot application , that writes critical errors to a separate log flle. I would like to create a ServiceNow ticket for each unique entry in the log file .  Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes... it can be achieved... you need to call servicenow API, whenever you log critical error...

Comment: Any other options rather than having servinow api in all micro services.  All our logs are in one central location.  Can ServiceNow connect to the centralized logging server and generates events from there?

Comment: ServiceNow supports webhooks which will be called when any change happens in any tickets. But that won't be useful here. you need to tell service now to create tickets instead of servicenow asking you if it can create tickets.

Answer (score 0):

you should have the option to trigger a script for the application logs. usually if you are using AWS cloud watch, you can trigger a lambda function and in the lambda function you can write a piece of code to trigger ServiceNow API for creating ServiceNow ticket.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_TableAPIPythonExamples.html